# Random-Number-Generator Error from "Data Analysis Tool" use in VBA script

Tags: vba, excel, random

I have created a VBA script which performs the statistical technique bootstrapping. My original sample is drawn from a Poisson distribution through the use of the Data Analysis Tool in excel (as there is no inverse build in excel function for Poisson distribution and I cannot think of any other way of simulating values from a Poisson distribution). However when I run my VBA script, I got this notification from its first iteration:

"Random Number Generation-Outputs range will overwrite existing data. Press OK to overwrite data in range:'[TestCoverage(Poisson,ss50).xlsm]ParametricBootstrap'!$B$2:$B$51"

I am aware of the "overwriting" demand when the Data Analysis Tool is used and for that reason I always check that the cells are empty before I operate the VBA script. But apart from checking myself that they are clear, I have incorporated in the model a specific part for clearing the contents of the cells that the problem is indicated in, just before the first time the Tool is used (line16), but still the VBA script acts like the cells are not empty showing this notification. By the time the VBA script reaches line22 (the operation of the Data Analysis Tool) it throws the previous message.

The peculiar part is that I have created an identical VBA script (as I have to evaluate bootstrapping for a pool of distributions) which draws the original sample from a Normal distribution, again with the use of the Data Analysis Tool, but in that case it operates normally.

This is the code:

```
Sub parametricbootstrappoisson50()

Dim iterations As Integer

iterations = InputBox("Please insert the number of times you want the bootstrapping process to be performed")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'These statements clear the results in the Coverage Results sheet existing from previous operations of the macro
Sheets("Coverage Results").Activate
Range("A3").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.ClearContents
Sheets("Parametric Bootstrap").Activate
Range("B2:C51").Select
Selection.ClearContents

For n = 1 To iterations

    'Creates an original sample from a Poisson distribution with parameter lambda P2 (mean)
    Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Random", ActiveSheet.Range("$B$2"), 1, 50, _
    5, , Range("P2").Value

    '1000 bootstrap samples and bootstrap means are produced and stored in the respective cells

    For i = 1 To 1000

        'Creates a bootstrap sample from a Poisson distribution with estimated parameter lambda Q2 (mean)
        Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Random", ActiveSheet.Range("$B$2"), 1, 50, _
        5, , Range("Q2").Value
        Sheets("Parametric Bootstrap").Range("E2").Offset(i, 0).Value = Sheets("Parametric Bootstrap").Range("R2").Value

        'Delete the bootstrap sample produced so that it will not need confirmation to overwrite the data when the next bootstrap sample will be drawn
        Range("C2:C51").Select
        Selection.ClearContents

    Next i

    'This is the process of transferring the results of the bootstrapping process to the Coverage Results sheet
    Sheets("Coverage Results").Range("A1:F1").Offset(n, 0).Value = Sheets("Parametric Bootstrap").Range("I2:N2").Value

    'Indication on whether the population mean is covered from the bootstrap confidence intervals of the nth iteration or not
    If Sheets("Parametric Bootstrap").Range("P2").Value >= Sheets("Coverage Results").Range("C1").Offset(n, 0).Value And Sheets("Parametric Bootstrap").Range("P2").Value <= Sheets("Coverage Results").Range("D1").Offset(n, 0).Value Then
        Sheets("Coverage Results").Range("G1").Offset(n, 0).Value = "Yes"
    Else
        Sheets("Coverage Results").Range("G1").Offset(n, 0).Value = "No"
    End If

    Sheets("Parametric Bootstrap").Activate

    'Delete the original sample produced so that it will not need confirmation to overwrite the data when the next original sample will be drawn
    Range("B2:B51").Select
    Selection.ClearContents

Next n

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Sheets("Coverage Results").Activate
Range("I2").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` ?

Comment: ClearContents clears the formulas from cells but leaves the formatting intact (the range is not completely empty). Try replacing all instances of `ClearContents` with `Clear`

Comment: I just figured out my mistake. In line29 I have the same cells to be filled as in line22 starting from B2, while the former should be starting from cell C2, so there is the part where it asks me to confirm overwriting, they were overlapping.

Thank you very much for your answers, they were helpful as I was not aware of these commands (I am a beginner in VBA). Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly an answer to your question, but I have had occasion to do simulations that required simulating Poisson random variables and have written my own user-defined function for it. It works by simulating a Poisson process and counting the number of arrivals within 1 unit of time. Remove the comment flag from `Application.Volatile` if you want it to behave like the worksheet function `Rand()` and recalculate whenever anything changes on the spreadsheet.

```
Function RandPoisson(lambda As Double) As Long
    'Application.Volatile
    Dim count As Long
    Dim x As Double, sum As Double
    Do While True
        x = -Log(Rnd()) / lambda
        If sum + x > 1 Then
            RandPoisson = count
            Exit Function
        Else
            sum = sum + x
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Loop
End Function
```

To test this, I wrote the following sub and compared the output with the built-in function `Poisson.Dist`:

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Long, p As Long
    Dim counts As Variant

    ReDim counts(0 To 9)
    Randomize
    For i = 1 To 1000000
        p = RandPoisson(3)
        If p < 10 Then counts(p) = counts(p) + 1
    Next i
    For i = 0 To 9
        Range("B2").Offset(i).Value = counts(i) / 1000000
    Next i
End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

Even though it involves a million simulations, it only takes about 1 second to compute.